# What is the easiest way to grep the command output?

Tags: linux, aix

I a trying to grep for certain string after issuing the `grpck -n ALL` command so when trying `grpck -n ALL | grep -i format`, for example, I still see the whole output and not just the lines containing the `format` string.

I know I could direct the output to a file and use grep on that file but it has to be an easier way.

The **grpck** is just an example as I have noticed other commands that don't support grep.

Comment: can you provide example input and output?

Comment: Commands do not "support" `grep` in a pipeline; you're just passing the output of the command to `grep`.  Provide both the stdout and stderr of your command, as `grpck -n ALL > /tmp/grpck.out 2> /tmp/grpck.err` then show the contents of each.

Answer (score 1):

The command `grpck -n ALL` returns an error in my system `invalid option -- 'n'`. This error outputs in stderr. I think you want to redirect stderr to stdout before using grep:

```
grpck -n ALL 2>&1 | grep -i sort
```

I changed 'format' to 'sort' because my output didn't have any 'format' in it.